# How can I let a user login to a server with SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have created a user account on my Ubuntu machine.

I want that user to be able to login with SSH. I guess I have to set some permissions in some file.

Googling for "SSH permissions" or "Setting SSH permissions" doesn't seem to find any useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `sshd` running, the user will be able to login via ssh by default.

Comment: I assumed so, I can login with SSH (either pwd or ss-key) with other accounts (someone else set that up), but not with this one. So I guess I'm confused.

Comment: I tried it anyway, got it started (it probably already was), now I am getting this error 'Permission denied, please try again.', which is what I got before.

Comment: Is "this one" root ? If so, check in file `sshd_config` (usually located in `/etc/ssh`) if `PermitRootLogin` is not set to `no`. Otherwise you can also check in the same file if there is a `AllowUsers` directive (which defines which users are allowed to login, like the name suggests).

Comment: Thanks, actually there is an `AllowGroups` directive. I had to add the user to the sshusers group. Done. It works, thanks.